# Referencing another struct in a struct where the second struct also references the first one

Tags: c++, struct

**Edit: Read the lines in bold to find where I'm having problems. I changed the code after reading the answers, but I'm still getting an error**

I'm new to C++ and I'm testing some things to get to know how to use the language and I came across this case:

I have a `struct` that creates a pointer to another `struct`. That other `struct`, in turn, creates a pointer to the `struct` that instantiated it in the first place.

Here's a quick example to explain what I mean a little bit better (this part has been changed with added code with lines in bold being where I'm having problems):

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Month;
struct Year;

struct Day{
    unsigned int day, dayNumber;
    string name;

    Day(){}

    void setDayNumber(unsigned int dayNumber){
        this -> dayNumber = dayNumber;

        switch(dayNumber){
        case 0:
            name = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            name = "Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            name = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            name = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            name = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            name = "Friday";
            break;
        case 6:
            name = "Saturday";
            break;
        }
    }
};

struct Month{
    string name;
    unsigned int monthLength, monthNumber;
    Month *previousMonth, *nextMonth;
    Year *year;
    Day *days;

    Month(unsigned int monthNumber, Year *year){
        this -> monthNumber = monthNumber;

        switch(monthNumber){
        case 0:
            name = "January";
            break;
        case 1:
            name = "February";
            break;
        case 2:
            name = "March";
            break;
        case 3:
            name = "April";
            break;
        case 4:
            name = "May";
            break;
        case 5:
            name = "June";
            break;
        case 6:
            name = "July";
            break;
        case 7:
            name = "August";
            break;
        case 8:
            name = "September";
            break;
        case 9:
            name = "October";
            break;
        case 10:
            name = "November";
            break;
        case 11:
            name = "December";
            break;
        }

        previousMonth = NULL;
        nextMonth = NULL;
        this -> year = year;
    }

    void createDays(){
        if(name == "January" || name == "March" || name == "May" || name == "July" || name == "August" || name == "October" || name == "December")
            monthLength = 31;
        else if(name != "February")
            monthLength = 30;
        else{
            **if(year -> isLeapYear() == true)** //This line is problematic, see below the code to see what the compiler says
                monthLength = 29;
            else 
                monthLength = 28;
        }

        days = new Day[monthLength];

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < monthLength; i++){
            days[i].day = i+1;

            if(i == 0 && previousMonth == NULL)
                days[i].setDayNumber(2);
            else if(i == 0)
                days[i].setDayNumber(previousMonth -> days[previousMonth -> monthLength - 1].dayNumber);
            else
                days[i].setDayNumber(days[i-1].dayNumber);
        }
    }
};

struct Year{
    unsigned int year;
    Year *previousYear, *nextYear;
    Month *months;

    Year(unsigned int year){
        this -> year = year;
        previousYear = NULL;
        nextYear = NULL;
    }

    void createMonths(){
        Month *currentMonth = months;
        unsigned int monthNumber;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            months = new Month(i, this);
        }

        while(currentMonth != NULL){
            monthNumber = currentMonth -> monthNumber;

            if(monthNumber == 0 && previousYear != NULL){
                months[monthNumber].previousMonth = &(previousYear -> months[11]);
                months[monthNumber].nextMonth = &(months[monthNumber+1]);
            }
            else if(monthNumber == 11 && nextYear != NULL){
                months[monthNumber].nextMonth = &(nextYear -> months[0]);
                months[monthNumber].previousMonth = &(months[monthNumber-1]);
            }
            else{
                if(monthNumber != 0)
                    months[monthNumber].previousMonth = &(months[monthNumber-1]);
                if(monthNumber != 11)
                    months[monthNumber].nextMonth = &(months[monthNumber+1]);
            }
        }

        currentMonth = months;

        while(currentMonth != NULL){
            currentMonth -> createDays();
            currentMonth = currentMonth -> nextMonth;
        }
    }

    bool isLeapYear(){
        if(year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Here are the messages the compiler outputs:

```
pe_019.cpp(107): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Year'
pe_019.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'Year'
pe_019.cpp(107): error C2227: left of '->isLeapYear' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Obviously, there's more to it than that, but in `Year`, I use an array of `struct Month`, and in `Month`, there's a pointer to its parent `Year`. (Same for `Day`, is has a parent `Month`).

When I try to compile, the compiler says I'm using an undefined `struct 'Month'`, that `Month*` has an unknown size, etc.

I'm pretty sure it's because `Month` is used before it is declared, but I can't declare it first because then `Year`will be the undeclared `struct`.

What's the correct way of going about this?

**Edit:** I forward-declared Year and put Month before Year after reading the answers to this question, but I'm still encountering problems because of a function I hadn't included in my original post since I didn't think it was part of the problem, I edited my code to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be improved in several ways, as follows.

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

struct Year;
struct Day;

struct Month{
    string name;
    unsigned int monthLength;
    struct Month *previousMonth, *nextMonth;
    struct Year *year;
    struct Day *days;
};

struct Year{
    unsigned int year;
    struct Year *previousYear, *nextYear;
    struct Month months[12];
};
```

The most important problem that this fixes is that, though the definition of *Month* only specifies a pointer to a *Year,* the definition of *Year* actually includes whole *Months.*  Let's think about that for a moment, because there is something significant to learn here.  If the compiler does not yet know what a *Month* is, how can it decide how to lay out a *Year* in memory?  Answer: it cannot, because it does not even know the size of a *Month.*

Merely including a pointer does not bring this problem, because the compiler knows the size of the pointer even if it does not know anything about the type of the object pointed to.

Your code also needed some semicolons, plus a standard header inclusion, both of which I have added.

Good luck.

*Update in response to OP's comment below:*  Revised code is posted below.  Notice that, and how, it delays the definition of the affected function until the type the function needs has been fully defined.

(Incidentally, if my thoughts in the matter interest you, *using namespace std* is almost never recommended.  It defeats C++'s useful namespace mechanism.)

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Month;
struct Year;

struct Day{
    unsigned int day, dayNumber;
    string name;

    Day(){}

    void setDayNumber(unsigned int dayNumber){
        this -> dayNumber = dayNumber;

        switch(dayNumber){
        case 0:
            name = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            name = "Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            name = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            name = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            name = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            name = "Friday";
            break;
        case 6:
            name = "Saturday";
            break;
        }
    }
};

struct Month{
    string name;
    unsigned int monthLength, monthNumber;
    Month *previousMonth, *nextMonth;
    Year *year;
    Day *days;

    Month(unsigned int monthNumber, Year *year){
        this -> monthNumber = monthNumber;

        switch(monthNumber){
        case 0:
            name = "January";
            break;
        case 1:
            name = "February";
            break;
        case 2:
            name = "March";
            break;
        case 3:
            name = "April";
            break;
        case 4:
            name = "May";
            break;
        case 5:
            name = "June";
            break;
        case 6:
            name = "July";
            break;
        case 7:
            name = "August";
            break;
        case 8:
            name = "September";
            break;
        case 9:
            name = "October";
            break;
        case 10:
            name = "November";
            break;
        case 11:
            name = "December";
            break;
        }

        previousMonth = NULL;
        nextMonth = NULL;
        this -> year = year;
    }

    void createDays();

};

struct Year{
    unsigned int year;
    Year *previousYear, *nextYear;
    Month *months;

    Year(unsigned int year){
        this -> year = year;
        previousYear = NULL;
        nextYear = NULL;
    }

    void createMonths(){
        Month *currentMonth = months;
        unsigned int monthNumber;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            months = new Month(i, this);
        }

        while(currentMonth != NULL){
            monthNumber = currentMonth -> monthNumber;

            if(monthNumber == 0 && previousYear != NULL){
                months[monthNumber].previousMonth = &(previousYear -> months[11]);
                months[monthNumber].nextMonth = &(months[monthNumber+1]);
            }
            else if(monthNumber == 11 && nextYear != NULL){
                months[monthNumber].nextMonth = &(nextYear -> months[0]);
                months[monthNumber].previousMonth = &(months[monthNumber-1]);
            }
            else{
                if(monthNumber != 0)
                    months[monthNumber].previousMonth = &(months[monthNumber-1]);
                if(monthNumber != 11)
                    months[monthNumber].nextMonth = &(months[monthNumber+1]);
            }
        }

        currentMonth = months;

        while(currentMonth != NULL){
            currentMonth -> createDays();
            currentMonth = currentMonth -> nextMonth;
        }
    }

    bool isLeapYear(){
        if(year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

void Month::createDays(){
    if(name == "January" || name == "March" || name == "May" || name == "July" || name == "August" || name == "October" || name == "December")
        monthLength = 31;
    else if(name != "February")
        monthLength = 30;
    else{
        if(year -> isLeapYear() == true)
            monthLength = 29;
        else
            monthLength = 28;
    }

    days = new Day[monthLength];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < monthLength; i++){
        days[i].day = i+1;

        if(i == 0 && previousMonth == NULL)
            days[i].setDayNumber(2);
        else if(i == 0)
            days[i].setDayNumber(previousMonth -> days[previousMonth -> monthLength - 1].dayNumber);
        else
            days[i].setDayNumber(days[i-1].dayNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm getting further now, but I still have some problems, can you look at my edited OP? I still have a line that make the compiler output an error (compiler messages included and the line is in bold). AS for the semicolons, I had them in my app, it's just that I forgot to add them back when I removed some parts of my code for the example

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that as I'm new to C++. It works perfectly! As for the "using namespace std", I haven't used namespaces all that much yet since, like I said, I'm new to C++, but I'll keep that in mind and try to use what's good practice from now on. Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamSmith: `using namespace std;` isn't a good practice, tbh; quoting from ##c++ @ FreeNode: "Importing the entire std namespace into the global scope brings in a lot more symbols than vector and list; it also brings in standard library implementational details. C++ headers are allowed to include other C++ headers, so there is no way of knowing just what symbols got pulled into global scope. It's best not to use 'using namespace std;'."

Answer (score 2):

I think you can forward declare them like this:

```
// Declare type year, since we need it to create a pointer
// We can finish the type later
struct Year;

struct Month{
    string name;
    unsigned int monthLength;
    struct Month *previousMonth, *nextMonth;
    struct Year *year;
    struct Day *days;
};

struct Year{
    unsigned int year;
    struct Year *previousYear, *nextYear;
    struct Month months[12]; // We need to know how big Month is here
};
```

The reason it works is that the compiler doesn't need to know anything about the types when it's using them (since they're pointers), it just needs to know that those types exist.

EDIT: I actually had to move `Month` before year, since it needs that information for `struct Month months[12];`

Comment: This answer does not seem to compile on GCC 4.4. Doesn't it want semicolons after the type definitions?

Comment: @thb - Yeah probably. Sorry, I just copied the code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Move the definition of `Month` first and forward-declare `Year`.

```
struct Year;
struct Day;

struct Month{
    string name;
    unsigned int monthLength;
    struct Month *previousMonth, *nextMonth;
    struct Year *year;
    struct Day *days;
}

struct Year{
    unsigned int year;
    struct Year *previousYear, *nextYear;
    struct Month months[12];
}
```

For an array of months, `Year` needs the full definition of `Month`.

In `Month` you only have a pointer to `Year`, so a forward-declaration is enough.

Note that in C++ the `struct` keyword is redundant - you can replace, for example `struct Year *year;` with just `Year *year;`.

Comment: Thanks, I omitted the struct keywords, but I added them afterwards after reading some posts after looking on Google, I guess it's a C thing? As for declaring Month first, is it because of the Month months[12]? Could I have put Year first if that line was Month *months and I dynamically allocated the memory using new?

Comment: This answer does not seem to compile on GCC 4.4.  Doesn't it want semicolons after the type definitions?

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Year;

struct Month{
    string name;
    unsigned int monthLength;
    struct Month *previousMonth, *nextMonth;
    struct Year *year;
    struct Day *days;
};

struct Year{
    unsigned int year;
    struct Year *previousYear, *nextYear;
    struct Month months[12];
};
```

This is the way it must be done. As `Month` uses only a pointer to `Year`, it doesn't need to know it's exact size and therefore `Year` doesn't need to be complete type before `Month`s declaration. However, `Year` uses array (non-dynamic) of `Month`, so it has to know `Month`s exact size.

---

**Edit** after OP edited the question:

The problem you are encountering is easy to solve. http://ideone.com/n4NYy - here is your code copied and compiled; as you can see, the problem is that `Year` is incomplete type at the moment when the function is being implemented; just move it outside the struct declaration, **after** declaration of `Year`. That's one of the reasons not to keep declarations and implementations together, within the struct/class body in C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful info, that solved my problems. I didn't know you could do it that way (or rather, I didn't remember since I had seen tutorials for classes with .h files and all of that but didn't think it applied to this particular case). You answer will help tremendously in the future, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Move setDayNumber() out of declaration of the struct:
Day::setDayNumber(...)
{
}